# How to write a event bridge rule with target as a stepfunction

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-cloudformation, aws-step-functions, aws-event-bridge

I am writing the AWS event-bridge rule in a yaml file

```
TriggerStepFunction:
  EventBusName: events-bus
  EventPattern:
    account:
      - ${AWS::AccountId}
  State: "ENABLED"
  Targets:
    step_function:
      - logical_id: eventStepFunction
```

I would be pass everything to the stepfunction without filtering so i kept the EventPattern as

```
EventPattern:
    account:
      - ${AWS::AccountId}
```

and target will be my stepfunction so providing the stepfunction logical id

```
Targets:
    step_function:
      - logical_id: eventStepFunction
```

After deploying, AWS event-bridge rules Targets it is not showing anything. I Think i am doing something wrong

Comment: CloudFormation?  SAM?

Comment: its Cloudformation

Comment: Permissions? Have you created a IAM role assumable by EventBridge,  and a policy  allowing  the  `states:StartExecution` action on your step function?

Comment: Actually it's weird I changed the Rule name then i could able to see the Targets in the configuration